# Emacs open another shell in current window

Tags: shell, emacs

One small thing that has been bugging me with emacs

When opening a shell within a buffer i do:

`M-x shell`

So far so good

But if I want to open another shell, I switch to another buffer and:

`C-u M-x shell`

*but* this always opens in another window - *not* the one I am currently in

this is annoying does anyone know how to fix it?

EDIT

I should have added that i have multiple buffers open in multiple split windows, e.g. my frame is split into 3 sections - what i want is the new shell to open in the same section that currently has focus,  i.e. the one i am typing in and not an alternate one

I think what happens when I do `C-u M-x shell` is that the new shell buffer opens in the *next* window, i.e. the one you would shift to if you hit `C-x o`. I want it to open in the *same* window

Comment: What version of emacs are you using ? I can not reproduce your pb with emacs24. And just because I like it, do you know about `shell-pop` ? With only one key stroke a shell buffer pops up. https://github.com/kyagi/shell-pop-el (available through ELPA).

Comment: GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.12) of 2012-09-22 on akateko, modified by Debian

Comment: Ok so I confirm this pb exists with emacs23 but not with emacs24. All I can do.

Comment: so if you have say a frame open split in two, on the left buffer is *shell\*, from in that buffer you do: C-u M-x shell then *shell*<2> opens in the same split window, i.e. the one on the left, not the one on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs runs [interactive shells](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html) in dedicated buffers.  It cannot run a shell in, say, TeX buffer.

<kbd>M-x shell</kbd> creates a new shell if there isn't one already, and <kbd>C-u M-x shell</kbd> asks you for the name of a new buffer. You can also rename the shell buffer to facilitate multiple shells, see the link above.

EDIT: the new shell buffer is displayed using `pop-to-buffer-same-window` (in Emacs24).
Your best venue is to add `*Shell*` to [`display-buffer-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html) - but it is not necessary there.

In Emacs23 the display of the `*Shell*` buffer is controlled by `special-display-function` (since `*Shell*` has a match in `special-display-buffer-names` or `special-display-regexps`). Set `special-display-function` to `display-buffer-same-window` (or something similar) and you should be golden.

However, the ultimate solution is to upgrade Emacs to v24; since you are on a linux system, it should be straightforward.

Comment: can confirm that upgrading to emacs 24 fixed the issue (sudo apt-get install emacs24)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following codes to force the "*shell*" buffers display in the same window.

```
 (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
     '("^\\*shell\\*" . (display-buffer-same-window . nil)))
```

Comment: This probably isn't what the question poster was looking for, but it is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Note this restores original behavior. Somewhere between Emacs v24.5.1 and Emacs v27.1 the shell behavior was *changed* so it no longer opened shell buffers in the same window. This is the kind of gratuitous behavior change that is supremely irritating when you've been using a tool for something like 40 years. Thank you very much for this; I had finally had enough and was looking for precisely this solution.